# Is it legal to search for another job while holding a J1 Visa?

Tags: usa

If you are working on a J1 summer program and for some reason you want to change your job, is it legal to search for other jobs and attend interviews on your free time?

If you get a new job purposal, and your actual employer agrees to make the transfer, is it achievable?

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, it is legal. Just as you had to go through the whole hiring process for the first time. You cannot start working, however, until all the legalities are formalized and the work authorization is transferred to the new employer. You should, of course, verify with a licensed immigration attorney, IANAL.